# Angular2 and ag-grid - how to pin filter menu

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using the enterprise version of ag-grid in my angular2 app.  The filter menu displays when the user hovers over it.  How do I pin the menu so that it always appears? Here's a sample column definition:

```
      {
        headerName: 'Name', field: 'name', width: 160, lockPinned: true, lockVisible: true,
        filter: 'agSetColumnFilter', lockPosition: true, pinned: 'left',
        filterParams: { selectAllOnMiniFilter: true, suppressMiniFilter: false},
        sortingOrder: ['asc', 'desc'],
        menuTabs: ['filterMenuTab'],
        colId: 'Name'
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code was needed:  `this.gridOptions.suppressMenuHide = true;`